# why css on Background displays when page loaded..?

Tags: css

I have a junk of css in background but when i load the page the css shows the all the tag and css that I have applied what should I do to not showing that background css and tag when we are loading the page?

Any Idea Friends?

background CSS means

```
suppose i am displaying only two buttons like login and signup and on
clicking of signup or login the another div comes as a form for it so when 
I am loading the page it is not directly showing only login and signup
button but first for fraction of second it is showing the both the form then 
that two buttons
```

Here's [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhaviksjoshi91/43sr06v6/9/)

at Js Fiddle you will not be able to see the effect but when I load the page both the div loginPage as eel as Signup Page Displays for a short Time then only that two button is being Display

What can be the Reason behind that?
is that hide operation ? or something else or is it that hide operation that what to do for hiding them in starting ?

Comment: Not clear what you want

Comment: I am also having the same problem

Comment: Actually when I load the page so the background css displays for a fraction of time and then they hide .

Comment: Actually what I am doing on document.ready I am hiding all tag that are not nessesary is it bcoz of that?

Comment: What do you mean by Background css, the code??

Comment: Try to post some code, so people can know where your problem lies. A fiddle would be much appreciated.

Comment: suppose i am displaying only two buttons like login and signup and on clicking of signup or login the another div comes as a form for it so when i am loading the page it is not directly showing only login and signup button but first for fraction of second it is showing the both the form then that two buttons

Comment: Please create a fiddle

Comment: I don't know how to create but let me try

Comment: whats your javascript code to hide and show that form...try to create a fiddle of what have you done

Comment: Rather than hiding them with javascript, hide them in html using `style=display:none;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than hiding your divs using javascript. Hide them in the html using `style="display:none;"`

[JS-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43sr06v6/10/)

```js
//$('#LoginPage').hide();
//$('#SignupPage').hide();

$('#login').click(function(){
    $('#LoginPage').stop().toggle('slow').animate(1000);
});
$('#signup').click(function(){
    $('#SignupPage').stop().toggle('slow').animate(1000);
});
```

```css
input[type=submit]
    {
        display:block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
input[type=text],input[type=password]{
        -webkit-border-radius:5px;
        -moz-border-radius:5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: solid 1px blue;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="loginsignup">
     <input type="button" id ="login" value="Login"/>
     <input type="button" id ="signup" value="Signup"/>    
      
</div>


    <div id="LoginPage" style="display:none;"> 
                <table align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Email :
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text"  id="unamelogin" name="unamelogin" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Password :
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="password" id="pswlogin" name="pswlogin" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
               <input type="submit" id ="loginsubmit" value="Login"/>
            </div>


<div id="SignupPage" style="display:none;"> 
                <table align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Email :
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text"  id="emaillogin" name="emaillogin" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            UserName :
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text"  id="unamelogin" name="unamelogin" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Password :
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="password" id="pswlogin" name="pswlogin" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Confirm Password :
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="password" id="pswagain" name="pswagain" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
               <input type="submit" id ="signupsubmit" value="signup"/>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:-
http://smallenvelop.com/display-loading-icon-page-loads-completely/